# Regex for matching block of text having a similar first line

Tags: python, regex

I have a string looking like that:

```
1.1 Title: title1 
line1
line2
line3
1.2 Title: Title2
line1
line2
line3
```

Is there a regex for matching each block starting by 1.x Title ? All my trials gave me either only the first line or all the file

Thanks for your help

Edit: the output would be a list of strings, in this case :

```
 s1 = '1.1 Title: title1 
     line1
     line2
     line3'
```

and

```
s2 = '1.2 Title: title2 
    line1
    line2
    line3'
```

and the number of line is not known, neither the number of 'block'

Comment: What would be the output?

Comment: If the amount of lines is constant, as shown in your example, then there's no need for regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lines are always consistent, you can use the following:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(?s)(1\.\d+\s+Title:(?:(?!\n1\.\d).)+)', s)
```

Or you can split those lines:

```
matches = re.split(r'(?m)\s+(?=^1\.\d)', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"(^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+?(?=\n\d.\d))|(^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+$)"gms` is what I came up with. It captures each group separately, though it isn't pretty.

Explanation from [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vQ7hC4/1):

```
"(^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+?(?=\n\d.\d))|(^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+$)"gms
  1st Alternative: (^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+?(?=\n\d.\d))
    1st Capturing group (^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+?(?=\n\d.\d))
      ^ assert position at start of a line
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      . matches any character
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      [^\n]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      (?:\D+\d)+? Non-capturing group
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        \D+ match any character that is not a digit [^0-9]
          Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \d match a digit [0-9]
      (?=\n\d.\d) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
        \d match a digit [0-9]
        . matches any character
        \d match a digit [0-9]
  2nd Alternative: (^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+$)
    2nd Capturing group (^\d.\d[^\n]+\d(?:\D+\d)+$)
      ^ assert position at start of a line
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      . matches any character
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      [^\n]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
      \d match a digit [0-9]
      (?:\D+\d)+ Non-capturing group
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \D+ match any character that is not a digit [^0-9]
          Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \d match a digit [0-9]
      $ assert position at end of a line
  g modifier: global. All matches (do not return on first match)
  m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
  s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```